# What's so funny about Ann's reply?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, fifty-shades-freed

In *Fifty Shades Freed* (2018), Christian, who has drank, speaks to his pregnant wife Ann:

> Christian: Babies mean no sex.
>
> Ann: **That can't be true. There'd be no siblings.**
>
> Christian: Hmm. You're funny.

She says people with babies have sex so that's how younger siblings are born
I don't think it's very funny.

What's so funny about her reply?